# How to simplify a constant to a root power?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would one simplify $5^{\sqrt5}$? A constant raised to a radical. Please show steps. On a calculator I get $36.554$.. Thanks you. Trying to see how it would be done on paper not just a calculator.

Comment: What do you mean "solve"? Find the value? Simplify?

Comment: Yes my bad find the value

Comment: It doesn't get "simpler" than that (but you can simplify $\sqrt 5^5$)

Comment: Are you looking for how to simpliy it or how to get 36.544... by hand?

Comment: @Ovi looking for both

Answer (score 3):

Compute or use tables to find the logarithm
$$x = \log_{10}5^{\sqrt{5}}$$
$$x = \sqrt{5} \log_{10}5$$
Then compute or use tables to take the inverse logarithm
$$5^{\sqrt{5}} =10 ^x$$

Comment: "Compute" and he just has paper and pencil. How could he ever find $x$ in the last step without the use of a calculator, please explain that.

Comment: Didnt work at all

Comment: @YashJain See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61279/calculate-logarithms-by-hand

Comment: @user522534 Computing the inverse log (base 10) of $\sqrt{5}\log_{10}5$ works on my calculator.

Comment: (+1) I think this is the correct way. Besides, as for this particular case, $\log 5$ is a decent memorable value (along with $\log 2$, $\log 3$ and $\log 7$)

Comment: @AndyWalls so if i take sqrt(5)Log(5) I get 1.562944.. so now ur saying take the inverse? Im confused

Comment: @user522534 yes.  The inverse log (base 10) of 1.562944 is $10^{1.562944} = 36.544..$