# Are exponents with a base very close to $1$ (such as $1.0001$) useful in Mathematics?

Tags: exponential-function, exponentiation

I was curious if exponents with a base very close to $1$ are ever used in Mathematics and for what applications.  For example, when I was in college, my Calculus professor told me that logarithms are mainly used as a "compression" tool so we can deal with very large numbers easier (such as $1$ million is ${10^6}$).  But if we choose a base such as $1.0001$, then we can effectively "expand" a small range of numbers (such as between $98.4$ to $98.8$) into a larger range.  I don't know if this has any usefulness in modern day Math but I was just curious.

btw, log base $1.0001$ of $98.4$ and $98.8$ respectively are about $45892.7$ and $45933.3$ so this might not be the best example but if the range was even tighter then perhaps using this method would be of some value.

I am also not sure what tag(s) to put this under so if anyone knows please go ahead and make an edit on this post.

Thanks.

Comment: [in this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469074/how-was-e-first-calculated/469088#469088) I quoted an explanation of why tables of logarithms were first calculated to base $1+\epsilon$ (actually the *very* first tables were calculated to base $1-\epsilon$).