# Derivation for Napier Logarithm

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, logarithms

Something new that I came across called the Napier Logarithm. I was reading the book “Computing: A Historical and Technical Perspective”, and the book says that
$$Nap.log x = 10^7(\log_e(10^7/x))$$
I am not really familiar with Napier Logarithms, but I want to know how this could be derived.

Comment: This has some info on Napier Logarithms: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47927/motivation-for-napiers-logarithms?rq=1

Comment: [This article](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/logarithms-the-early-history-of-a-familiar-function-john-napier-introduces-logarithms) looks as if it might be interesting from the historical point of view.  I believe the multiplication by $10^7$ is nothing but a device to avoid writing decimal points, so that you get for example $12345678$ instead of $1.2345678$.